# Is there an easy way to unpack a tuple while using enumerate in loop?

Tags: python

Consider this:

```
the_data = ['a','b','c']
```

With enumerate this loop can be written as:

```
  for index,item in enumerate(the_data):
     # index = 1 , item = 'a'
```

If `the_data = { 'john':'football','mary':'snooker','dhruv':'hockey'}`

Loop with key value pair assigned in loop:

```
for name,sport in the_data.iteritems():
 #name -> john,sport-> football
```

While using enumerate, the data becomes a tuple within the loop, hence needs one extra line of assignment after the loop declaration :

```
#can assignment of name & sport happen within the `for-in` line itself ?
 for index,name_sport_tuple in enumerate(the_data.iteritems()):
         name,sport = name_sport_tuple  # Can this line somehow be avoided ?
         #index-> 1,name-> john, sport -> football
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use this:

```
for index, (name, sport) in enumerate(the_data.iteritems()):
   pass
```

This is equivalent to:

```
>>> a, (b, c) = [1, (2, 3)]
>>> a, b, c
(1, 2, 3)
```

This is commonly used with `zip` and `enumerate` combo as well:

```
for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(seq1, seq2)):
    pass
```

Comment: you need the iteritems on his dict. :D

Comment: @AaronHall Good catch, I simply copied OP's last code snippet. :)

Comment: I have 2 questions: 1) What stops python from comprehend that unpacking procedure? 2) What if the number of lists in zip() was dynamic?